# Creating 2 'Total' rows using cross-tab: Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a following requirement where I need 2 'Total' field in row. As default we know we get one row by name 'Total' which gives us sum/distinct value of entire column, however I need 2 'total' rows back to back.

Requirement.
[image]

There are 4 rows and total under 'Skill' column, what I need is

1. 1st and 3rd row value(SUN) i.e. 2 + 0 = 2(Total)
2. 2nd and 4th row value(SUN) i.e. 2 + 0 = 2(Total)

I need 1st total from 1st and 3rd row and 2nd Total from 2nd and 4th row.

currently I am getting 'Total' of only 1st and 3rd row, I need 2nd and 4th row in second 'Total' row.

Please let me know if I am clear enough.

**UPDATE 1:**

here is my requirement, the report should look like this.
[image]

We have two total rows this will contain sum of break out skills and another total will have shifts.

Comment: Do you always have same columns (weekdays)? I would suggest to create 'normal' report then (without crosstab); maybe using helper query to pivot by weekdays.

Comment: Weekdays are handled already and NO it won't show all 7 days every time it depends on the count availability if there are no numbers then the column will be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add another row in the total ad hoc. What you could probably do is mimic the result you need. e.g. Add another section right below and build the necessary totals cells so that they align with the cross tab and give the appearance of being part of the same table. If we could see the nature of your raw data we could probably recommend a better solution.

Comment: Well 'Total' will sum up all the rows right? I guess I have to form a formula to sum only the 1st, 3rd, 5th... rows and even(2nd 4th 6th...) rows in an another total, is there a way to sum these the way I explained ?

Comment: It should be possible, but you need to provide a sample of the data for us to recommend a solution.

Comment: I have added a screen shot under UPDATE 1, please let me know it is understandable.

Comment: You can perhaps do the following.

Comment: You can perhaps do the following.

1. Create a formula that initiates the 14 Variables Shift_sun to Shift_sat and breakOut_sun to Breakout_sat. Please this formula in the report header.

2. Build another formula field that performs conditional calculation e..g if day of week = sun and type=breakout then breakout_sun=breakout_sun + value;

3. Build formulas to output the 14 variables at the bottom ad hoc rows.